# iOS SDK - Link static library with static library

Tags: ios, testing, static-libraries, libraries

I have the following issue: I am writing an app that consists of a main project for the GUI and similar and two static libraries: One for authentication to a service and a second one for using a part of that service. The problem is, that I need to use parts of the auth library in the service library for instance the auth library offers an API http client that I want to use in the service library.
I managed to get it running when building the whole app with GUI an everything but I didn't manage it to get in running if the service lib should be build stand-alone (for continues integration tests etc.) My deployment target is 5.0, my SDK is 6.1.
Is there a way to do this right™?
Thanks for any help.

Philip

EDIT: Of course I could just put the auth lib into the service lib as a sub project but if I need to use more then one service libs in a future app that would be quite messy, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue you are missing is:

## Static libraries are not linked.

They are simply an *archive* of object files, with Mach-O extending this concept to support multiple architectures in the same file (see `lipo`).

The only way multiple static libraries are linked together is in the final binary (app or dylib).

Comment: OK so what are my choices to get something where I can reuse my libs and can still test it with unit tests as a stand-alone version?

Comment: Your unit test apps need to link with all required libraries.  One option is to create an Xcode Workspace including all required static library projects and set-up the dependencies correctly.

Comment: OK that comment helped a lot. Thanks!